# Removal of decimal in HSSF cell

Tags: apache-poi, poi-hssf

i am reading data from an excel sheet which has decimals.

i want to obtain the result without decimals.

I'm using  `cell.getNumericCellValue ()` which gives decimal - is there a function which removes decimals.

Comment: Where are the connection to Javascript, Java, Apache and Struts? I think this an issue for Tag excel and if exists for HSSF.

Answer (score 4):

how about just casting the value to int?

```
(int)cell.getNumericCellValue()
```